# how to get zabbix item values in two different time for trigger?

Tags: monitoring, notifications, ubuntu-server, zabbix

In zabbix for monitoring my some database parameters, I need to create a trigger for checking an item value in every 15 minute and run if the last retrieve value is increase or decrease from now retrieve value.

Who to create that trigger?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `{YOUR_ITEM.change(0)}#0`

Comment: Can you add more information as to what this does?

Comment: @user2932202, Thank you so much. May i ask you describe it more?

Comment: According [to the documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/triggers) it returns difference between last and previous values.
For strings:
0 - values are equal
1 - values differ

Comment: So in case of changes you will receive alert: change(0) returns 1; trigger expression: 1 <> 0 (true) => alert